# What do I do when rebuild Smart Group Cache fails?

Tags: smartgroups

(Sorry, was hoping to not have to start a new Question but instead comment on another's but StackExchange doesn't allow it unless you have 50 points of privileges.)

```
CiviCRM 4.6.0
Joomla 3.4.1
```

I am getting errors on both manual use and cronjob:

Manual button in Groups:

> @import url(/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/css/civicrm.css); @import url(/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/jquery-ui/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css);    Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.  is not of the type Int
>
> [Return to home page.](http://alcoholjustice.org/administrator/)
>
> function toggle( element ) { var className = element.className; if ( className == 'crm-accordion-wrapper collapsed crm-fatal-error-details-block') { element.className = 'crm-accordion-wrapper crm-fatal-error-details-block'; } else { element.className = 'crm-accordion-wrapper collapsed crm-fatal-error-details-block'; } }

Scheduled Jobs (cronjob):

> Parameters raw (from db settings): 
>   limit=Number optional-Limit the number of smart groups rebuild
>
> Parameters parsed (and passed to API method): 
>   a:2:{s:7:"version";i:3;s:5:"limit";s:56:"Number optional-Limit the number of smart groups rebuild";}
>
> Full message: 
>   Finished execution of Rebuild Smart Group Cache with result: Failure, Error message: A fatal error was triggered:  is not of the type Int

Answer (score 4, accepted):

could you create a new issue for this on JIRA and link it as related to https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-15816.

Comment: Sure thing. Thx. ;-)

Comment: Created https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16288

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'll save someone some time until there is some sort of integrated fix or if these are just flukes (however, I see them on multiple sites).

On one site with only one smart group: 
I disabled it
I created a new smart group
Successfully ran rebuild system cache!

It seemed to clear up an error in our dblog about htmlentities (htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in CRM_Utils_Type::escape() (line 261 of sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Utils\Type.php)) and also mailing issues to that smart group.

Tonight I'll try to disable all of my smart groups on another site, run the rebuild and see if it clears it up there.

**Update:**
On site with multiple smart groups, I went to Manage Groups, clicked on Contacts for each Smart Group and on one group, I got the error message about is not of the type Int.

All other Smart Groups correctly displayed the contacts within that group.

So I disabled that Smart Group and successfully ran Rebuild Smart Group Cache.

If I re-enabled that group and ran the  rebuild again, the htmlentities error came back.

Comment: on the site with multiple, does it work if you delete the smart group and recreate it? I think we had this once: the group broke for reasons unknown, but recreating fixed it and it hasn't recurred.

Comment: In my experience, smart groups can break between upgrades, when the search form / database schema changes and the smart group is still expecting to see the old schema.

Answer (score 0):

Try PR created at [this link](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/6437) which fixes some searches leading to DB error. May be, it should be able to fix your issue.