# Want to send Testmail for Mailing, but get Error.

Tags: civimail

I want to make a test for my mailing, but get this error:

```
Error in call to Mailing_send_test : Error in call to MailingJob_create : DB Constraint Violation - possibly mailing_id should possibly be marked as mandatory for this API.
```

Want could be the failure? I use CiviCRM Version 4.6.2. on Apache with MySQL

Comment: Was this a new install of 4.6.2 or an upgrade?

Comment: relativ new install

Comment: the same erro apears when click on '(Estimating)' - next to the selection of recipients

Comment: ok, add a new mailing a tryed again the testmailing - know it works!!! Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 2):

Try upgrading to 4.6.3. Several mailing-related bugs were fixed in that release.

Comment: now i am on 4.6.3 but the error still there...

Comment: We are experiencing the same error on 4.6.3.

Comment: In our case, I think it has something to do with Smart groups.  Something is munged up with them it seems.

Comment: If your test included a smart group, I found some resolution for our issue here: http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/489/what-do-i-do-when-rebuild-smart-group-cache-fails/3781#3781

Answer (score 2):

After upgrading to 4.6.3 I added a new mailing and tried the test mailing again. Now it works!!! **Thanks for your answers!**

Comment: Please click the checkbox next to this answer to mark it "Accepted"